# Round up duration between two times if difference exceeds 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two dates which are generally the start_time and end_time. I want to take the difference between the times and round up the hours component if the minutes component is > 10 minutes. For example:

- difference of 12 minutes - round up to 1 hour
- difference of 1 hour 31 minutes - round up to 2 hours
- difference of 2 hours 4 minutes - keep at 2 hours
- difference of 3 hours 59 minutes - round up to 4 hours

So here is the code what I am able to achieve until now. I am finding the difference between the two dates and diving it by 3600000 and rounding it up but that is something like converting 1 hour 30 minutes to 2 hours.

```
 var duration = Math.round(moment(end_time).diff(moment(booking_result.start_time))  / 3600000);
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: What format are end_time and booking_result.start_time? They must be ISO to be accepted by moment() otherwise you need to specify the format moment(end_time, 'x')

Comment: they are in ISO and I am able to find the difference

Comment: Do you mean you want to take any difference greater than 10 minutes and round up to the next hour? So 31 minutes difference would be 1 hour,  1 hour 12 minutes would be 2 hours, 2 hours 3 minutes would still be 2 hours?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie yes exactly

Comment: @RobinMackenzie thanks for your edit!

Comment: sac Dahal, did it work? If so, could you please check the answer as valid?

Comment: sure I am just testing it will check once and valid it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you're using momenjs then it's easy what you want to do:

```
var duration = moment.duration(end_time.diff(start_time));
var hours = duration.asHours();
```

that will give you the duration in hours with decimals, as I understand from your question you want to do is round this upwards to the nearest integer, but only when this difference has more than 10 min. in the minutes component so:

```
if (duration.minutes() > 10) {
    var result = Math.ceil(hours);
}
```

Comment: Check my edit per OPs comment - they only want to round up where the minutes component of the delta > 10 minutes. E.g. duration of 2 hours and 3 minutes stays at 2 hours, but duration of 2 hours 11 minutes rounds up to 3 hours.

Comment: it worked just had a minor change                         var duration = moment(end_time).diff(moment(booking_result.start_time));
                        var countDuration =  moment.duration(duration);   var hours = countDuration .asHours();

Comment: Oh, that's because your date variables weren't moments... Glad to help!